# React-native / Redux - error with state

Tags: react-redux

So far I have been following various tutorials. This time I'm trying to build things from scratch (kind of). For now the following is supposed to display part of state. Later on I'll play with making it do calculations,etc. Still I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

So I use mapStateToProps and the first step I'd like to do is to get it to display this.props.count and this.props.step. Once I've done it I'll modify it to do more complex things.

Here's the component and below there's a link to the whole code that I put on github.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getCounter } from '../actions';

class CounterBoard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>BELOW SHOULD DISPLAY 0</Text>
        <Text>{this.prop.count}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    count: state.count,
    step: state.step
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCounter })(CounterBoard);
```

https://github.com/wastelandtime/calculator

Edit: Thank you for the 'prop' => 'props' pointer. Now I have the following error:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:63 Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {count, step}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Text`.
```

Comment: you have this.prop, should be this.props.

Comment: Thank you - that's solved one problem. See my update above

Answer (score 0):

After going through your code on Github, I couldn't help but notice that in your action, you return the following object:

```
export const getCounter = (count) => {
   return {
    type: GET_COUNTER,
    payload: count
  };
};
```

If you intend to return the count, I assume that action.payload should contain a number here and not an object.

However, in your reducer, you return:

```
case GET_COUNTER: 
  return action.payload.count;
```

Assuming from the code in your CounterBoard Component and CalcReducer, you probably wanted to merge your payload into the initial state before returning from the reducer?

You might also need to pass and argument while dispatching the `getCounter` action, for the component to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you. Please accept my apologies but could you elaborate. I thought I'm getting the whole redux mechanism - but it seems I'm not.